# share perl module state between tests

Tags: perl, module, global, state

I am using Test::More and I have a helper function that takes a while to run. I need to use this in several test scripts. I would like to save the result of running this function, so that the state can be accessed by all the scripts. The result of calling the function does not change for each test.

I have created a module like this:
    package Helper;

```
our $_global_state = under;

sub helper {
    if ( !defined( $_global_state)) {
        #insert magic here to set the _global_state
        print STDERR "Inside magic\n";
    }
    return $_global_state;
}

return 1;
```

However, if I call this function from several test scripts, it redoes the 'magic' each time. I am trying to avoid this if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be solved using the following:

- Save the calculated state to a file.
- If the file isn't last modified in say 10 minutes, recalculate the value.

Using [`Storable`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Storable;

our $state_file = 'global.state';

sub helper {
    # Check to see if file last modified in 10 minutes.
    if (-e $state_file && -M $state_file < 1/24/6) {
        return retrieve($state_file);
    }

    #insert magic here to set the _global_state
    my $global_state = {'a'..'d'};

    store $global_state, $state_file;

    return $global_state;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd helper();

1;
```